# How to extract substring from a string?

Tags: r, string, substring

There are some strings which show the following pattern

```
ABC, DEF.JHI
AB,DE.(JH)
```

Generally, it includes three sections which are separated with `,` and `.`  The last character can be either normal character or sth like `)`. I would like to extract the last part. For example, I would like to generate the following two strings based on the above ones

```
JHI
(JH)
```

Is there a way to do that in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
 str1 <- c("ABC, DEF.JHI","AB,DE.(JH)")
 str_extract(str1,perl('(?<=\\.).*'))
#[1] "JHI"  "(JH)"
```

`(?<=\\.)` search for `.` followed by `.*` all characters

Answer (score 1):

You can just split on the `.` using `strsplit` and extract the second element.

```
str1 <- c("ABC, DEF.JHI","AB,DE.(JH)")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(str1, "\\."), "[", 2))
# [1] "JHI"  "(JH)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, "\\.\\(|\\.|\\)"), "[[", 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing on @josiber's answer you could remove the part of the string before the `.`

```
str1 <- c("ABC, DEF.JHI","AB,DE.(JH)")

gsub(".*\\.", "", str1)
# [1] "JHI"  "(JH)"
```

**EDIT**

In case your third element is not always preceded by a `.`, to extract the final part

```
str1 <- c("ABC, DEF.JHI","AB,DE.(JH)", "ABC.DE, (JH)")

gsub(".*[,.]", "" , str1)
# [1] "JHI"   "(JH)"  " (JH)"
```